# UIPicker view problems

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

Ok lets try this one more time, I have a picker in my app and it is working fine with this code here

```
_fuglar = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Allt árið", @"Hrafn", @"Svartbakur",@"Silfurmáfur",@"Sílamáfur",@"Frá 20.ágúst til 15.mars",@"Grágæs",@"Heiðagæs",@"Frá 1.september til 15.mars",@"Fýll",@"Dílaskarfur", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerView Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return _fuglar.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [_fuglar objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
//Create UIImage objects
UIImage * uglaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ugla1.jpg"];
UIImage * ravenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"raven.jpg"];
UIImage * svartbakurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"svartbakur2.jpg"];
```

Then I want to centre the text in the picker and change colour also and I am using this code for that but then my picker just goes blank but I can see the pictures, any ideas?

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
return label;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When populating a picker view, you implement either titleForRow, or viewForRow, not both. By implementing viewForRow, you're substituting your view for the default label. To fix the problem, delete the titleForRow method, and set the text of your label in viewForRow:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (row == 0 || row == 2) {
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }else{
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    label.text = [_fuglar objectAtIndex:row];
    return label;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is solved now :) Can you maybe help me with one more thing, what would I do if I only want first line and third line blue in my picker row.

Comment: @Sleeperinn, put an if-else statement in viewForRow, and return blue  when  (row ==0 || row ==3) , and whatever other color you want if that condition is not met.

Comment: Im sorry but can you please show me how, I am new to programming @rdelmar

Comment: @Sleeperinn, I've edited my answer (it should have been row 0 or 2, not 0 or 3 as I said in my comment).

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my hero :)

Comment: Is there any chance that I could send you an email, I have another project that I am having problems with @rdelmar.

Comment: @Sleeperinn, sure, I'll take a look at it if it's not to complicated. My email is rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: Thank you, I have sent you a mail.